# C# UWP Adding scrollbar,margin,border to pivotItem

Tags: c#, uwp, pivot, uwp-xaml, stackpanel

I am creating Windows UWP  app that displays weather forecasts from a nestedlist `sortedDays` . It contains days on the Outer list and hourly forecasts in the inner list. (using pivot)I am trying to display in each pivotItem, a separate stackPanel for every hourly forecast so that each `pivotItem` will have numerous stackPanels of hourly forecast.

Unfortunately my data is running off the bottom of the screen and I cannot seem to get a scroll bar working. I have also been struggling with adding  any form of margin or boarder around the `hourStack` stackPanels. As the data is is coming from a nested list generated from an API I feel it must be added through c# code and not xaml(open to opinions). I have looked up the documentation but cant find anything that works through c#

```
 //dynamically add a pivot item
        PivotItem pvt;
        ScrollViewer scroll;

        //loop through SortedDays to seperate Day and hour forecasts 
        int xCount = 0, yCount = 0;
        foreach (var sd in myForecast.SortedDays)
        {// Define a ScrollViewer

            scroll = new ScrollViewer
            {
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible
            };
            pvt = new PivotItem
            {
                Header = myForecast.SortedDays[xCount][0].dayOfWeek

            };
            var dayStack = new StackPanel();

            foreach (var sh in sd)
            {
                var hourStack = new StackPanel
                {
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center

                };

                var timeBlock = new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = myForecast.SortedDays[xCount][yCount].dtime,
                    FontSize = 30
                };
                hourStack.Children.Add(timeBlock);

                var tempBlock = new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = "Tempeture (c)\t:" + System.Convert.ToString(Math.Truncate((myForecast.SortedDays[xCount][yCount].temp - 273.15) * 100) / 100)
                };
                hourStack.Children.Add(tempBlock);

                var descBlock = new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = myForecast.SortedDays[xCount][yCount].desc
                };
                hourStack.Children.Add(descBlock);

                var windBlock = new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = "Windspeed\t:" + System.Convert.ToString(myForecast.SortedDays[xCount][yCount].windSpeed)
                };
                hourStack.Children.Add(windBlock);

                var humBlock = new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = "Humidity\t:" + System.Convert.ToString(myForecast.SortedDays[xCount][yCount].humidity)
                };
                hourStack.Children.Add(humBlock);

                // append hourStack to dayStack
                yCount++;
                dayStack.Children.Add(hourStack);
            }
            scroll.Content = dayStack;
            // set dayStack as pivots content
            pvt.Content = scroll;

            // add pivotItem to pivot
            pvtWeather.Items.Add(pvt);

            pvt = null;
            xCount++;
            yCount = 0;
        }
```

WeatherPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="WeatherForecast.WeatherPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WeatherForecast"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Pivot x:Name="pvtWeather"  Margin="100,100,100,100" Height="1200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="True">



    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying to set above properties code behind, actually all the elements and styles used in above code snippet could be defined in XAML.  For your scenario, `PivotItem` is strongly recommended to bind with data sources. Details for binding please reference [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart). And a nested list could be bound to  `Pivot` control.

Just for example, you may define the entities as follows:

```
public class Daylist
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TimeTemperature> Temperatures { get; set; }
}

public class TimeTemperature
{
    public string currenttime { get; set; }
    public string winSpeed { get; set; }
    public string humidity { get; set; }
    public string temperature { get; set; }
}
```

So that the nested list could be created as follows:

```
public ObservableCollection<Daylist> daylists { get; set; } 
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    daylists = new ObservableCollection<Daylist>
    {
        new Daylist {Day="Wednesday" ,Temperatures= new ObservableCollection<TimeTemperature>
        {
            new TimeTemperature {currenttime="2018-3-14 00:00:00",temperature="7.72",winSpeed="11.67" ,humidity=".95"},
            new TimeTemperature {currenttime="2018-3-14 01:00:00",temperature="7.72",winSpeed="11.67" ,humidity=".95" },
            new TimeTemperature {currenttime="2018-3-14 02:20:00",temperature="7.72",winSpeed="11.67" ,humidity=".95"}
            ...
        }},
        new Daylist {Day="Friday" ,Temperatures= new ObservableCollection<TimeTemperature>
        {
             new TimeTemperature {currenttime="2018-3-14 00:00:00",temperature="7.72",winSpeed="11.67" ,humidity=".95" }
        }}
    };
}
```

And now we can define the elements in XAML and bind data source to `Pivot` and `PivotItem`, the layout can be simply updated. For your requirements, using a `ListView` for `Pivot.ItemTemplate` to show the data , it will auto scroll when records are overflow. You can also add `Margin` and other properties as you want.

```
<Pivot x:Name="Pivot1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind daylists}">
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Daylist">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Day}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Daylist">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Temperatures}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TimeTemperature">
                            <Grid Margin="20">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Text="{x:Bind currenttime}" />
                                <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Text="winSpeed:" />
                                <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Text="{x:Bind winSpeed}" />
                                <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Text="humidity:" />
                                <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Text="{x:Bind humidity}" />
                                <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Row="3"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Text="temperature:" />
                                <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Row="3"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Text="{x:Bind temperature}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

More details please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlPivot).

Comment: Believe it or not changing the height of the pivot to 500 sorted this whole problem. But I am liking your idea I will look into it thanks

Comment: @MidnightP, simply changing height may work since `ScrollViewer` only work when content overflow from a limited area. But I thinking `ListView` with binding should be the better way for you.

Comment: I understand but all this data is coming from an API so implementing this might get tricky. Is it possible to have a `foreach` inside the `      daylists = new ObservableCollection<Daylist>
    { `  statement?